# How to make a custom recycler view with many adapters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerView and two type of rows, one with a textView and a switch for a response boolean, and another with a textView and an editText for String. 
i have an API which has a name and a type if it's a boolean or a string. 
How can i make different rows with these two types which i don't know the count of each one of them, but i have the count of all of them.

row_critere_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView_row_critere"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/editText_critere_"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_critere_boolean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView_row_critere_boolean"/>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/switch_critere_boolean"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i have two arrays

```
  List<String> nameCritere = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> typeCritere = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Layout is not too complex and there is no much `layers` so I suppose you could play with `visibility`. You could `include` your second layout `row_critere_boolean.xml`  inside first one `row_critere_edit_text.xml` and by checking inside `onBindViewHolder` is `boolean` or `string` make corresponding `layout`: `gone` or `visible`.

Comment: yeah! you're right. Why didn't i think about it earlier ! thank you